# PHP If Statement Value Present

Tags: php, variables, echo, if-statement

How would you make a if statement that echo's if a variable has a value in it and if it has no value in it, it does not echo anything.I know you would use else if there wasn't a value and I know how to make if statements but I don't know how I would use one to determine if a value is present or not.
Like

```
if($additional == ' '){}
else{echo 'Additional information:', $additional;}
```

Comment: "variable has a value in it" - By value, do you mean a certain string?

Comment: @hellohellosharp Like if the variable has any data in it echo it and if it is black echo nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!empty($variable)){
      echo $varibale     // if the condition check its not empty it will output it
}
else{
     // do nothing      - while when your variable has no value it will do nothing in else
}
```

***But even if you don`t put else nothing will be output since your condition state that you should echoed that variable if it has a value .......***

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to do this in a way that doesn't generate a notice or warning? As others noted an empty variable will result in no output, but if it's not defined at all you generate errors, which your could shouldn't do.

```
echo $value ?: '';
```

That should do it

Edit: note this is PHP 5.4 syntax. Older PHP versions use

```
echo isset($value) ? $value : '';
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question being asked. The OP was very clear in wanting an 'if' statement.

Comment: Is there a way to do it like I did it in my question...I tried to make something that would work.

Comment: This is a ternary operator, commonly treated as a short hand if/else statement. It's not typical for a request for an "if statement" to need to be taken so literally that it excludes a ternary, but thanks for the downvote and absolutely garbage feedback Ian.

Answer (score 1):

```
If (isset($variable)){
Echo $variable;
}
```

Please check PHP documentation for isset and echo

You asked for an if statement which will trigger an echo, the above will do it

Edit:you are checking if the variable is empty? Then this could be used also

```
If (empty($variable)){
Echo "variable is empty";
}
Else
{
Echo "variable is not empty'";
}
```

Two solutions which you could implement, both work as you require

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
if(isset($additional))
       echo "Additional information: ".$additional;
else
       echo "Empty";
```

Answer (score -1):

Echoing a blank variable and echoing nothing are pretty much the same thing. In this case, you really just need:

```
echo $value;
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question being asked. The OP was very clear in wanting an 'if' statement.

Comment: True, but when asked for clarification he said "@hellohellosharp Like if the variable has any data in it echo it and if it is black echo nothing" which my code does.